# TYPO3 reactivate deleted page

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I would like to make a deleted page visible again.

If I now set the respective page deleted from 1 to 0 in the database under "pages", it still does not appear in the page tree. You can't find it in the recycle bin either.

Anyone have any ideas how to reactivate the site?

Comment: Check if the parent page is deleted too. The uid of the parent page is stored in the `pid` field. So `SELECT pid FROM pages WHERE uid=xy`. Check the "deleted" field on this page (and go on to the grandparent etc until you hit a page which is not deleted).

Comment: Keep in mind that the order/position is also deleted. So the reactivated page has its former parent page, but may be the last subpage now.

Answer (score 0):

Undeleting a deleted page can be done hardcore in the database, but that would require also undeleting the content of that page in the same way.
As you have not found that page in the recycle bin you have not selected the parent page. Either you was in the wrong page or that parent page also is deleted, which means you need to undelete it too. Here it may be helpful if you have a look into the database table getting the parent page (`pid`) of your deleted page (and maybe further parents) up to a visible page.

Using the recycler to undelete may be better than just a database update on the records as it may update (restore) more then just the `deleted` field. This may include related records or references.